# will there be any issue for my system if I upgrade my database which is oracle 11.1.0.6 to 11.1.0.7

Tags: oracle

I'm working on Oracle 11.1.0.6 and planning to upgrade it to 11.1.0.7. What are the expected issues I'm going to face? P.S: it's for banking system

Comment: Whatever issues you encountered when you did the upgrade in a lower environment and performed a full regression test.  Short of that, no one knows whether your particular application on your particular hardware with your particular workload would have any particular issues.

Comment: Do you have extended support? Getting support from Oracle in case it goes tits-up would be my biggest worry (what with 11.1.x being unsupported unless you have an arrangement with Oracle)

Answer (score 3):

*Test it* is the answer. Minor upgrades should not give problems but if you do not test your application you will not be sure.

Answer (score 2):

11.1.0.7 is so far out of support that it's not even funny (end of support was August 2015 for "extended" support - see http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lifetime-support-technology-069183.pdf).

Given that you *will* (presumably) be doing a full-scale regression test for any upgrade of this scale, why choose to land on an unsupported version, when you could move to a supported version?

It'd be a two-step upgrade for you (11.1.0.6->11.1.0.7->12.1.0.2), but long-term, it's a better position to be in.

To directly answer your question, you'll find out what issues you'll face by doing a full regression test.  That's the only way.